# Get Referrer Url in php codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, http

I am not sure if this is doable or not, but i am trying to find the original source on how the user actually reached our site. This is to display an example of the flow.
Lets say our site is xyz.com
User reached our site in this manner

A.com -> B.com -> xyz.com

Is it possible to know A.com because $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] will only provide me with B.com. Even, if it is doable with .htaccess will be great

Any ideas/suggestion will be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Not unless you are able to modify A.com or possibly B.com and/or anything else along the path.  You would pretty much have to grab the referrer at each stage and pass it along.

Comment: Thank you @AbraCadaver. Thats what i figured, because i dont have access to A.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$referralSource = 'direct';
if (isset($_COOKIE['Referral_Source']) && filter_var($_COOKIE['Referral_Source'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $referralSource = $this->db->escape_str($_COOKIE['Referral_Source']);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your codes.

Comment: I think this will only work if you have access to A.com.  Otherwise, your solution does not apply